# child element covering parent element

Tags: html, css

Basically the way my site is layed out, I have some elements that have a full width background beyond the content page  (e.g. having the nav bar background go across the page completely).  So basically what I decided to do was create another `div` within the content `div` , and for the nav bar it worked, however for the next section of the site, for some reason , the child element covers over its parent element in all browsers. I dont understand why as it seems to work for the nav bar section.

Here is the CSS

```
#top-slider {
width:100%;
height:400px;
background: #222; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #f1f1f1);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #f1f1f1);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#fefefe), to(#f1f1f1)); /* older webkit syntax */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #f1f1f1);
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 2px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 2px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 2px; 
float:left;
padding-bottom:20px;
position:relative;
width:980px;


}

#top-slider-full-bar {
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
width:99999px;
background: #222; /* Show a solid color for older browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #f1f1f1);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #f1f1f1);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#fefefe), to(#f1f1f1)); /* older webkit syntax */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fefefe, #f1f1f1);
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 2px;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 2px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0px 1px 2px; 
height:400px;
```

}

Here is the site, http://limerickchambers.hailstormcommerce.com as you can see, it seems to be working fine for the nav bar...
Ive tried `z-index` but that seems to have no effect.
limerickchambers.hailstormcommerce.com

Thank you

Comment: No offense, but there are problems with your code actually, what i dont get, you have an id named page, you wrapp all your content with it that is 980px wide, and than you place a 99999px width in it positioned absolute, it shows the cover because its positioned absolute, if i can give you an advice rebuild your page structure logic on this one

Comment: I took that advice thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing your html structure to something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/KpTHz/

This would make it all much easier to manage.

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">HEADER</div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">CONTENT</div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">FOOTER</div>
</div>


.outer {
 width:100%;
 background:#ccc;
}

.inner {
 width:920px;
 background:#999;
 margin:0 auto 20px;
 padding:20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this makes more sense, am I right in thinking that on smaller screens and mobiles the width of the `inner` will take up the screen due to `px` being set? Its just I dont want the center of the screen to have the content with wide gaps on either side on mobiles etc.

Comment: In my example above the width of the site is 960px (920 + padding of 20px on left and right). You can change that to be anything you like. Any screen will show you the 960px width plus whatever else outside that that it has room to show.

Comment: Thanks I made the changes and the new layout makes much more sense. I knew I was going about it in a weird way, especially seeing as its something quite simple. 

Although I have to say, I still dont really fully understand why it was covering it in the first place, even with attemped correction of z-index.